# No value given for one or more required parameters. c# oledb

Tags: c#, parameters, oledb

Not sure where the problem is. No value given for one or more parameters. I've tried moving the code out of the if statements but it hasn't helped. Not sure if the data adapter requires me to enter all of the column values.

```
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(txtStudent.Text);
        string grade = "A";
        int result = Convert.ToInt32(txtResult.Text);

        string sql = "UPDATE Student SET grade=@grade WHERE ID = ?";

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connectionString);





        if ((result >= 70) && (result <= 100))
        {
            grade = "A";
            MessageBox.Show("Result is: A");

            command.Parameters.Add("@grade", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = grade;
            command.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ID;



        }

        else if ((result >= 60) && (result < 70))
        {
            grade = "B";
            MessageBox.Show("Result is: B");

            command.Parameters.Add("@grade", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = grade;
            command.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ID;
        }

        else if ((result >= 50) && (result < 60))
        {
            grade = "C";
            MessageBox.Show("Result is: C");

            command.Parameters.Add("@grade", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = grade;
            command.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ID;
        }

        else if (result < 50)
        {
            grade = "F";
            MessageBox.Show("Result is: F");

            command.Parameters.Add("@grade", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = grade;
            command.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ID;
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect data entered");
        }



        OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Student");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "Student";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem on that line;

```
OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connectionString);
```

You add your parameters on your command but you *still* using `sql` string which expects parameter and their values in `OleDbDataAdapter` constructor.

Use your command instead of your sql query;

```
OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command, connectionString);
```

And use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection`, `OleDbCommand` and `OleDbDataAdapter` automaticaly.

As your second problem, from the documentaion of [`OleDbCommand.Parameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters):

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text.

Actually, it *does* support named parameters but names are negligible. Only matter is your parameter orders. Since you add `@ID` parameter your command first, this will be added to your first parameter in your command that you defined which is `@grade`. As you can see, this will generate a problem.

Change your parameters order as well;

```
command.Parameters.Add("@grade", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = grade;
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ID;
```

Comment: That's definitely one problem - and it explains the error message. I'll temporarily leave my answer in as well, as the next issue the OP will run into. If you want to merge that into your answer, I'll delete mine...

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure Jon. I completed my answer as you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: I'm still having some difficulty, I've updated the command.parameters.add like you said and I've changed OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);

Comment: @Andrew What is the _difficulty_ exactly? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I now get child list for field student can not be created